# convert csv to json for javascript plotting library chartjs in Python or PHP

Tags: python, json, csv, converters, chart.js

I have a set of query results in CSV format.

I need to parse those results into something that i can load into my javascript chartjs for plotting results

how to i convert in Python or PHP my csv file to the right Json format used in the JS below?

*Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday,...*

*314,225,666,...*

in particular the INT value needs to be without quotes else it wont load correctly. All functions i have found enclose all labels and values in double quotes "label", "value":"int"

```
    <script>

$("#myLine").dxChart({
    dataSource: [
        {day: "Monday", oranges: 314},
        {day: "Tuesday", oranges: 225},
        {day: "Wednesday", oranges: 345},
        {day: "Thursday", oranges: 464},
        {day: "Friday", oranges: 626},
        {day: "Saturday", oranges: 126},
        {day: "Sunday", oranges: 4246} ],

    series: {
        argumentField: "day",
        valueField: "oranges",
        name: "My oranges",
        type: "bar",
        color: '#ffa500'
    }
});


    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The high level process flow I would suggest is:

- read csv
- convert to python dict/list data structure
- convert data structure to json string
- send the json string to your javascript

for help with reading the csv you can have a look at the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Once you have data build your structure something like:

```
list_of_day_oranges_pairs = [('Monday', 314) ....]  # getting to this format should be easy 
data = [{'day': day, 'oranges': oranges} for (day, oranges) in list_of_day_oranges_pairs]
```

Then convert the data to json:

```
data_string = json.dumps(data)
```

Now that data_string is ready to be sent to your javascript

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  Could you suggest what is the best way to load into my dataSource directly from my .json data source file which resides on the httpd root folder?

Comment: Thanks, please disregard my last comments I understood wrongly part of the solution.